# Generate UUID with GWT

Tags: gwt, uuid

Is there any way to generate UUID with GWT?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate an UUID in GWT by reusing a [Javascript UUID implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/439171) an wrapping it using JSNI:

```
public native static String uuid() /*-{
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
            function(c) {
                var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r
                        : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
                return v.toString(16);
            });
}-*/;
```

If you want just an unique ID (not an UUID) to use in your GWT elements, use:

```
String id = DOM.createUniqueId();
```