# How to set UUID in PubNub GWT api?

Tags: java, gwt, pubnub

I found ways to set UUID in java,ios but can't find a way to setUUID in GWT api (com.pubnub.gwt.api.client.Pubnub)

Comment: refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759590/generate-uuid-with-gwt]. This might help you.

Comment: i'm not talking about generating any random UUID but setting a UUID to com.pubnub.gwt.api.client.Pubnub object by "pubnub" api.
Like in ios this is the api:
[PubNub setClientIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier]; // Change UUID
but i can't find similar api for GWT.

Comment: @gndp PubNub will enable this functionality for you, please standby.

Comment: @Geremy can you provide ETA?

Comment: @gndp please contact us at support@pubnub.com so we can best prioritize this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using pubnub gwt jar available here

https://github.com/pubnub/java/raw/gwt-uuid/gwt/3.3/api/PubnubGwt.jar

The uuid you want to set can be passed to init method . Sample usage here

https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/gwt-uuid/gwt/3.3/examples/PubnubExample/src/com/pubnub/gwt/examples/client/PubnubExample.java#L101

'gwt-test-uuid' is the custom uuid in this case